# How to call a stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an stored procedure in mysql workbench. I am trying to call it with in php and I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\storedProcedure1.php on line 9

$res = mysql_query($connection, "CALL getPlayers1()") or  
  die("Query fail to launch:".mysql_error());
```

Any advice please?

By the way my stored procedure is the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetPLayers()
    begin
    select player_id, name, gender, playing_career,dob,place_of_birth
    from players;
    end $$
```